# Web API app with OWIN 'SystemWeb' on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-web-app-service, katana

I am creating app which uses Identity 2.1.0 framework in .NET. I started project in Visual Studio 2015 as Empty Web App (template). Now, I use `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin`, and also `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` NuGet packages in my project. I understand that OWIN is a specification made to avoid monolithic frameworks and to specify how smaller application components interact with servers. However, I have requirement to deploy to Azure App Services.

I have found examples (blogs) where people deploy OWIN Web Api app as self-hosted to the Azure Cloud Services worker role. But I don't want this, as I don't use Cloud Service.

Since I am using `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`, am I going to be able to deploy this to Azure App service (which I assume manages internal IIS instance) ?

.NET ecosystem newbie here - so please excuse me for any possible redundancies in the question.

Comment: Cloud Services in Azure are hosted within IIS. And that's what the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` (Katana) assembly is for - to run Owin-compliant apps within IIS. I don't see why you'll have any problems hosting this WebAPI app on Azure Web Role.

Comment: That is correct! I just tried to Publish project to the newly created Azure Web App plan, and it succeeded without any issues. I was just afraid that I have chosen wrong path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` is designed for hosting in IIS and all Azure App Service web apps are hosted in IIS, so this is exactly what you want (In fact, self-hosting likely won't work with Azure App Service).