# does using owin make sense when using Azure web sites

Tags: azure

I have a simple web API 2.0 that I want to host in azure websites. Do I need owin for this or does owin only make sense when you are using Azure Web worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Web API based on Owin works just fine in Azure Web Apps, as long as it's configured to be IIS-hosted. You do not have to use Owin of course.

Here's a related question and answer: [Owin app in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35045109/1658906)